# RXJS 5 - Emit a single composite value from an array of observables when all sources emit

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs-lettable-operators

I'm composing multiple observables using an observable's `pipe` method and I'd like to emit a final composite value when all observables in the array emit.

```js
import { apiSvc } from '../lib/api-service'

import { of as observableOf } from 'rxjs/observable/of'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

const uris = [
  '/api/items/1',
  '/api/items/2',
  '/api/items/3'
]

observableOf(uris).pipe(
  // Map uris array to an array of observables.
  map((uris) => calls.map(uri) => apiSvc.get(uri) /* returns observable*/),
  // Perform magic and emit when all calls complete.
  magic()
)
.subscribe((results) => {
  console.log(results) // [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
})
```

I was able to make this work with `forkJoin`:

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin'

observableOf(uris).pipe(
  // Map uris array to an array of observables.
  map((uris) => calls.map(uri) => apiSvc.get(uri)),
)
.subscribe((requests) => {
  // Emits when all request observables emit.
  forkJoin(requests).subscribe((results) => {
    console.log(results) // [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
  })
})
```

...but I'm looking for a way to get it done in the `pipe` chain without having to nest `subscribe` calls.

The `zip` operator is sort of in the ballpark but it doesn't appear to work on arrays of observables. Is there a lettable operator that works like `forkJoin` and can be used with `pipe`?

Comment: Substitute map with mergeMap followed by reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. You want to return the `forkJoin`ed Observable inside the chain and wait until it emits with `concatMap` (`mergeMap` will work as well here).

```
observableOf(uris)
  .pipe(
    // Map uris array to an array of observables.
    concatMap(uris => forkJoin(uris.map(uri => apiSvc.get(uri))),
  )
  .subscribe((responses) => {
    ...
  });
```

Comment: And all the people said, "alakazam!"

Comment: Bonus question: if I wanted to emit each `apiSvc.get()` response when it emits, i.e., as they come in, is there a `forkJoin` counterpart that will "pass through" each response? Thanks in advance.

Comment: WRT the above comment/question, Instead of `concatMap` I added `mergeMap(req => from(req))` followed by `mergeAll()` to the chain. I suppose I have to use the second `mergeAll` because merge-mapping `from(requests)` emits observables. Not sure if there's a more concise expression, but that gives me the calls one-at-a-time as they come in, instead of all at once in an array.